# Product quantity doesn’t update on WooCommerce's cart page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product-quantity

after reading many similar topics, I still can’t solve this problem; the quantities in the cart don’t update with the new values once the **“update cart”** button is clicked.

I’ve already tried disabling themes and plugins, but even as the only extension installed and with default theme (tried both *StoreFront* & *Twenty Twenty-one*), the WooCommerce cart continues to behave this way. I have also enabled the WordPress debugging logs and I can’t find anything there, just like in the console.

Someone already run a debug on my cart and think that I am a victim of a code conflict, he found this error :

```
Element.querySelectorAll: '\' is not a valid selector
```

I don't know where to look for the source of this error or what procedure to follow to recover the expected behavior...

You can try the bug [here](https://cornulus.ch/panier).

***Mini-update :*** I created a new Wordpress project and installed WooCommerce. I then transferred all the files of this new WooCommerce on my site and the problem still persists.

I also noticed that the columns of the *woocommerce_sessions* table were not updated when the quantity was changed. I assume that the script responsible for writing to this database could be the cause of this bug.

Comment: Provide your website URL so we can see the console area if it is something related to selectors.

Comment: You are right, I added a link to the cart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I could not find the source of the problem, I started from scratch by changing my hosting solution. Once the files were uploaded on the new server and the configuration files were adapted, the shopping cart works normally again.